# ¿Como obtener el primer documento de una coleccion en cloud firestore para android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

estoy haciendo consultas en firestore, lo que busco es que me el contendio de X document, por ejemplo: quiero mostrar lo que haya en el primer documento dentro de una coleccion. tengo el siguiente codigo

```
  //limit es donde especificas cunatos documentos quieres obtener
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Consultas").orderBy("d1").limit(1)
                        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
{
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) 
  {
    QuerySnapshot document = task.getResult();
    if (document.exist)
    {}
```

Mas realmente no se como proseguir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro del exist proba la siguiente linea.

```
String descripcion = document.getData().get( <nombre del campo> ).toString();
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: Buenisimo, ¿Podrás marcar la respuesta como útil?. Gracias de antemano